# pandas dataframe row proportions

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe with multiple columns and rows

For all columns I need to say the row value is equal to 0.5 of this row + 0.5 of the row befores value.

I currently set up a loop which is working. But I feel there is a better way without using a loop. Does anyone have any thoughts?

dataframe = df_input

```
df_output=df_input.copy()
for i in range(1, df_input.shape[0]):
    try:
        df_output.iloc[[i]]= (df_input.iloc[[i-1]]*(1/2)).values+(df_input.iloc[[i]]*(1/2)).values
    except:
        pass
```

Comment: Create a column using `pandas.DataFrame.shift` and then create your final column using `0.5 * cur_val + 0.5 * lag_val`. No need for a loop, should be super quick, and then you just drop the column you don't need. There is no example data in your question, so I'm not providing an example solution.

Comment: great thanks. Would this work for multiple columns do you think?

Comment: yes not sure how to make a example dataframe yet. Only know how to load in csvs

Comment: What do you mean? Do you need a complex calculation like `0.5 * cur_val + 0.5 lag_val_1 + 0.5 * lag_val_2 + ... + 0.5 * lag_val_n`?

Comment: nope. just the same calculation for multiple columns in the dataframe... so col1, col2, col3, etc all having the same adjustment

Comment: Ah, gotcha. Hmm... a vectorized function that performs element-wise calculations that can be applied to each column in a loop might be better. So, basically, you'd want to write a function that took in an entire column of data and then offset it slightly such that you had `x1 = col1[1:]` and `x2 = col1[:-1]` and then do `0.5 * x1 + 0.5 * x2`, which would operate element wise. You could then loop over each column and feed it into this function to get your results back.

Comment: thanks that makes sense. Thanks alot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you mean sth like this:

First creating test data:

```
np.random.seed(42)

df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0, 20, [5, 3]), columns=['A', 'B', 'C'])

    A   B   C
0   6  19  14
1  10   7   6
2  18  10  10
3   3   7   2
4   1  11   5
```

Your requested function:

```
(df*.5).rolling(2).sum()

      A     B     C
0   NaN   NaN   NaN
1   8.0  13.0  10.0
2  14.0   8.5   8.0
3  10.5   8.5   6.0
4   2.0   9.0   3.5
```

**EDIT:**
for an unbalanced sum you can define an auxiliary function:

```
def weighted_mean(arr):
    return sum(arr*[.25, .75])

df.rolling(2).apply(weighted_mean, raw=True)

       A      B     C
0    NaN    NaN   NaN
1   9.00  10.00  8.00
2  16.00   9.25  9.00
3   6.75   7.75  4.00
4   1.50  10.00  4.25
```

**EDIT2:**
...and if the weights should be to be set at runtime:

```
def weighted_mean(arr, weights=[.5, .5]):
    return sum(arr*weights/sum(weights))
```

No additional argument defaults to balanced mean:

```
df.rolling(2).apply(weighted_mean, raw=True)

      A     B     C
0   NaN   NaN   NaN
1   8.0  13.0  10.0
2  14.0   8.5   8.0
3  10.5   8.5   6.0
4   2.0   9.0   3.5
```

An unbalanced mean:

```
df.rolling(2).apply(weighted_mean, raw=True, args=[[.25, .75]])

       A      B     C
0    NaN    NaN   NaN
1   9.00  10.00  8.00
2  16.00   9.25  9.00
3   6.75   7.75  4.00
4   1.50  10.00  4.25
```

The division by `sum(weights)` enables the definition of weights not only restricted to fractions of one, but by any ratio:

```
df.rolling(2).apply(weighted_mean, raw=True, args=[[1, 3]])

       A      B     C
0    NaN    NaN   NaN
1   9.00  10.00  8.00
2  16.00   9.25  9.00
3   6.75   7.75  4.00
4   1.50  10.00  4.25
```

Comment: yes this looks perfect. Don't really understand how you've done that as I thought rolling was for moving averages. but yes that looks good.

Comment: there is 1 further complication, that its not always going to be 0.5:0.5. It might change to 0.25:0.75 in the future

Comment: `rolling` is not rolling average, but rolling window. the average would be `rolling(2).mean()`- but you can have different aggregation functions behind this rolling window

Answer (score 1):

```
df.rolling(window=2, min_periods=1).apply(lambda x: x[0]*0.5 + x[1] if len(x) > 1 else x)
```

This will do the same operation for all columns.

Explanation: For each rolling object the lambda chooses the columns and `x` are structured like `[this_col[i], this_col[i+1]]` for all cols, and then doing custom arithmetic is straightforward.

Answer (score 1):

Some

```js
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(low=0, high=10, size=(5, 1)), columns=['a'])
df["cumsum_a"] = 0.5*df["a"].cumsum() + 0.5*df["a"]
```

thing  like below?